# Can i tie the enable pins directly to the rails?

Tags: pullup, pulldown, enable

i am having trouble with the spaces on my circuit and removing the two pull-up/down resistor on the enable pins would solve my problem ( if of course it doesnt cause other problems). I was wondering if i could  completely removes the resistor and directly tie them to the rails. They are not connected to a GPIO that toggles them they are meant to be a fixed state.

The first is the pull up from the enable pin of [LP5907](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lp5907.pdf?ts=1596414428626&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). There already seems to be a weak 1M ohms pull down built to it internally.

[image]

Second is the [TMUX1574](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tmux1574.pdf?ts=1596414270775&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F). This also have a weak 6M ohms pulldown internally.

[image]

Would it be safe to skip these resistors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet you link for the first one.

> the application does not require the use of the shutdown feature, the EN pin can be tied directly to the IN pin to
> keep the regulator output permanently on.

No pullup needed.

For the second:

> Active low enable: When this pin is high, all switches are turned off. When this pin is low, SEL pin controls the signal path selection. Internal 6 MΩ pull-down to GND.

You can leave it disconnected and it will be on. If 6 Megaohm isnt enough for a stable on, you could connect directly to ground without issue.

Comment: Thank you vey much for the confirmation good sir.